# C# failing to set string value - instead setting \0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I am debugging a unit test. The code below in the unit test class clearly sets a string to a value of "2". But the debugger is translating it to (see screenshot) "\0". I changed changing the string value to a different value with n characters, and it showed as n \0's. I.e. \0\0\0\0\0\0.

The unit test also fails because of this.

I tried changing the value to the immediate window back to 2, and then unit test passes.

```
password2 = "2";
```

Why is Visual Studio / C# having trouble assigning a value of 2 to string?

[image: \0]

Comment: I would give a try to _Clean Solution_, _Rebuild Solution_. It seems like your debug is not really synchronized with the source code.

Comment: It could be an old assembly reference in the debug, do a clean build on your unit test.

Comment: Before you rebuild, ensure your build configuration is Debug.

Comment: Is this the value observed before executing the `Decript` method or after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoke to the developer and the test was bad. It also was not being picked by the CI, so it was a perfect storm. The test was using RtlZeroMemory to zero out the memory reference, which I had not seen before.

Thank you to you all who spent time investigating.

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[Guid("...")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class FileEncryption
{
    [DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "RtlZeroMemory")]
    public static extern bool ZeroMemory(IntPtr Destination, int Length);

    public void Decrypt(string filenamewithpath, string password)
    {
        // We manually control memory and free when it is completed
        GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(password, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
            ...
            ZeroMemory(gch.AddrOfPinnedObject(), password.Length * 2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            gch.Free();
```